# How to make links in element availible when clicking on this element checks a checkbox?

Tags: jquery

I have links inside an article element. While clicking on the element a checkbox achieves checked attribute. But links inside this element are inactive.

How could i improve this script to make the links available?

http://jsfiddle.net/57GsC/

```
<article class="post short-post">
   <header><h3 class="post_title"><a href="/posts/2">Yo</a></h3></header>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="post_check" class="post-check center-align">
    <div class="post-body">Mauris nec nisl justo. Suspendisse quis metus venenatis turpis feugiat euismod ac semper arcu. Vestibulum </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="links">
         <a class="edit button" href="/posts/2/edit">Edit Post</a>
         <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" class="delete button" href="/posts/2">Delete a Post</a>
         <a class="view button" href="/posts/2">View</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</article>

$(".short-post").click(function(evt) {
  var $checkbox;
  if (evt.target.type !== "checkbox") {
    $checkbox = $(":checkbox", this);
    $checkbox.attr("checked", !$checkbox.attr("checked"));
    evt.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Why did you build this click function so that the checkbox is changed when you click on the whole area including the links ? Why not simply attach your handler to an area excluding the links (or using `label`) ?

Comment: Your question is bit unclear.

Do you want to enable the links when checkbox is checked? If yes which links?
Do you want checkbox to be checked only when "Yo" is clicked? or even if someone clicks on "Edit Post" link checkbox should be checked?

Please do specify.

Comment: No i need the whole area to be able to check the ckeckbox. But the links inside must be abailable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links are disabled because you return false at the end. Returning false after catching a click event on a link tag stops the link from executing.

Comment: Can i also made it the checkbox not checking when clicking on the links? :) Thanks

Comment: What's the point then, if you don't want have it checked? Isn't that a totally normal checkbox then?

Answer (score 0):

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/EgLmG/) I just removed the jquery code and used the standard `label` element which seems to do what you intend to do (and what your users probably expect).

```
<input id=someId type="checkbox" value="" name="post_check" class="post-check center-align">
<label for=someId>Mauris nec nisl justo. Suspendisse quis metus venenatis turpis feugiat euismod ac semper arcu. Vestibulum </label>
```

I'm assuming here you don't want to do 2 actions on a simple click (change a checkbox and follow a link). I you'd really want to you could of course simply not return false but that's terrible for the user.

Comment: Unfortunately i can`t use label for the post`s body.

Comment: You could have hooked your handler to the post body, then.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `return false;` statement